# Retrofit 500 internal server error

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a post registration webserivce as the following

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register/default")
Observable<BaseResponse> doRegistration(@Field("name") String name,@Field(value = "email",encoded = true) String email,@Field("phone_number") String phone_number,@Field("password") String password,@Field("password_confirmation") String password_confirmation);
```

I've tried with postman to consume this service , and it replies with the response of registration , from android side it causes an exception (500 internal server error ) ,
 when and only using a symbol `@` on the email field , also i've tried the encode option flag mentioned above, UTF-8 encoding but it doesn't interpreted as an email by server side.
is there is a retrofit related issue !

Comment: Do you try `@Field("email") String email`

Comment: Relevant: Log requests and responses on android, read  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses. Log requests and responses on server. Figure out what's wrong inbetween. Jumping straight to the assumption that *tried and tested v2.2* Retrofit does something wrong is foolish. ***|||*** Unrelated: I'm pretty sure you can check string equality on client side (password vs password_confirmation).

Comment: Thanks it was related to server side add new record on table .

Answer (score 0):

It was a server related issue on creating new record so larvae returns the default exception response with internal server error.